# problem with registering visiting days

Tags: support

I always log in to this site after my father is done. However he has more consecutive days than me. I have only 2. When/how does the site register a visit?

Comment: Can you give us a few more details? Do you and your father share the same account? If not, why is your father's account relevant? Times on the SE network tend to be calculating using [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Maybe you log in after midnight UTC so it doesn't count the day you expect it to count?

Comment: We don't share the same account, but we log in when we have a break between meals ( we are cooks ). Between 15,00 en 17.00 and after 21.30 local Spanish time. Every day, so I really don't understand this. (We share the laptop, different user accounts.) But thanks for responding.

Comment: possible dupe of [Buggy consecutive days counter](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20001/buggy-consecutive-days-counter)