# Consecutive days counter not working as expected

Tags: support

Although I made a comment yesterday, it didn't register my visit.

[image: screenshot showing I commented yesterday]

I had 69 days and today it shows 1. Clicking on *Consecutive days* shows I missed yesterday. I was really on my way to 100. Very disappointing. And not the first time either. Can anyone fix this please?

Answer (score 6):

Your comment shows as two days ago (2022-04-23 14:56:04Z)

A day is based on a UTC timezone, so if you're a long way off that, it can be easy to not trigger an event every day.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only thing is I'm there every day, same hours, so time difference should have no effect, as it is always the same. Anyhow 1 plus.

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing is I'm there every day, same hours,

Visiting the site once per day (at roughly the same time) still makes you vulnerable to missing a day. Here's why:

Let's say in your timezone (as an example) you visit around 12:00 in the beginning of January - this is by chance the exact same time that day counter on Ask Ubuntu switches to the next day.

Let's then say on the one day, you visit at 11:59, and the next day you visit at 12:01.

Now, the first day you visit will be registered as January 1st on Ask Ubuntu. However, since you didn't visit in the interval 12:00-12:00 the following day, you next visit at 12:01 will register as January 3rd on Ask Ubuntu.

If you want to be sure this can't happen, you need to visit twice a day with 12-hour intervals - then this will never happen.

Comment: What are the odds that the OP visits at midnight every day? I fly to and from Canada - Sri Lanka twice a year. Sri Lanka to Canada, I arrive close to the time I left. Canada to Sri Lanka I arrive about two days later. It makes it hard to get a year of consecutive days.

Comment: I have no idea - but this seems to be working for everyone else, except that one person...