# What is happening with the daycounter?

Tags: support

I went to my account and clicked responses yesterday and it states that I made some responses and got an answer to my *Responses*. See screenshot:

[image: responses menu]

My day counter however states that I have not visited the page on July 28. What is happening with the day counter? Why are these 2 different?

Comment: Days are delineated using UTC. Depending on your local time zone, it is possible for you to visit on a particular day in your local time zone that doesn't correspond with the date in UTC.

Comment: Yes I know, but that doesn't explain 2 different things on the same website.

Comment: The responses section in your profile are not actions you took at all. If there are events there, it doesn't necessarily mean you were active on that day. You need to look at the "[All Actions](https://askubuntu.com/users/1450922/joepie-es?tab=activity)" section (you don't necessarily need to do any action to be active on a certain day though).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Buggy consecutive days counter](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20001/buggy-consecutive-days-counter)